# How can I change MaxRequestsPerChild in ssh?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, ftp

My website has been crashing after a minute of running with a fatal error saying it ran out of memory. Now, the memory being allocated, does not exceed the memory limit set in the php.ini file, so I'm thinking this has to do with an endless loop somehwere or a plugin not being compatible with another one.

To fix that I found online that people have changed the MaxRequestsPerChild setting on their websites to fix issues like this one. The problem is, I can't seem to find where and how to set that setting...

Comment: It'll depend on your distribution and server config... `/etc/httpd` for redhat based platforms `/etc/apache2` for debian. I don't think that config is related to your problem, but if it is, this will be better suited for [sf].

Comment: @msg I looked in the httpd folder for ‘Max’ to find the setting in all the conf files and could not locate the setting being mentioned anywhere...

Comment: Maybe because the parameter [was renamed](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mpm_common.html#maxconnectionsperchild), but should still be backwards compatible.